# Access to mirage internals (db) in development mode?

Tags: ember-cli-mirage

I know how to use 'db' to work with internal mirage database in tests but I did not found out if it is possible to access internals like 'db' in standard routes. I understand that my app has no knowledge that mirage is used so it might not be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirage's `db` is passed into route handlers as the first parameter, so you can access it there.

If you're talking about accessing it within your Ember app's routes (e.g. `Ember.Route.extend`), this is not really appropriate because Mirage is just a mock for your API and, as you say, your Ember app should have no knowledge of its data other than via XHR requests.

Comment: Thanks, I was talking about Ember.Route.extend